# JavaScript ES6 Generator Catch Error Before Next Method

Tags: javascript, generator

I start learn about **Iterator/Generators** and sometimes I saw some weird parts. Currently I don't understand why my code work like this.

In bellow code sample is my main code.

```
function* makeGenerator() {
    try {
        yield 1;
        yield 1;
        yield 1;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

const generator = makeGenerator();
```

When I use next method before throw this code work normally.

```
console.log(generator.next()); // { done: false, value: 1 }
console.log(generator.throw("WTF?")); // "WTF"
console.log(generator.next()); // { done: true, value: undefined }
```

```js
function* makeGenerator() {
  try {
    yield 1;
    yield 1;
    yield 1;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

const generator = makeGenerator();

console.log(generator.next()); // { done: false, value: 1 }
console.log(generator.throw("WTF?")); // "WTF"
console.log(generator.next()); // { done: true, value: undefined }
```

But when I want to use throw method before next method I don't understand why next methods not work?

```
console.log(generator.throw("WTF?")); // "WTF"
console.log(generator.next());
console.log(generator.next());
```

```js
function* makeGenerator() {
  try {
    yield 1;
    yield 1;
    yield 1;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

const generator = makeGenerator();

console.log(generator.throw("WTF?")); // "WTF"
console.log(generator.next());
console.log(generator.next());
```

Answer (score 3):

When this statement is executed:

```
const generator = makeGenerator();
```

...none of the code in the `makeGenerator` function body is executed yet, and so its `try/catch` block is not yet in effect. Only when you execute `generator.next()`, the code in the `makeGenerator` function body will start executing up until the next `yield`. At that point the `try/catch` block is in effect.

So... if you call `generator.throw()` *before* the first `generator.next()` call, you are triggering an exception that is not handled by the `makeGenerator` code. Your code breaks with an unhandled exception. As a consequence nothing that follows that `generator.throw()` (in your second code version) is executed.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of throwing errors via generators is to wrap them inside a `try...catch` because with not catching the error you're creating an error there, then, it falls through to the outer calling code (if any) and, if uncaught, kills the script.

```
function* makeGenerator() {
    try {
        yield 1;
        yield 1;
        yield 1;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

const generator = makeGenerator();
console.log(generator.next()); 
try {
  generator.throw(new Error("WHOOPS"));
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e); // shows the error
}
```